# Statistical Gaussian test for n-dimentional data in Python

Tags: python, statistics, gaussian

I have vectors that have 26 points of data in them, and I'd like to see if the distribution of said vectors is Gaussian. Is there a function or a methodology I can apply?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's called normality test. There is an awesome blog post about it check it out [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-normality-tests-in-python/).
Here is a sample snippet from the post called Shapiro-Wilk:

```
# Shapiro-Wilk Test
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import randn
from scipy.stats import shapiro
# seed the random number generator
seed(1)
# generate univariate observations
data = 5 * randn(100) + 50
# normality test
stat, p = shapiro(data)
print('Statistics=%.3f, p=%.3f' % (stat, p))
# interpret
alpha = 0.05
if p > alpha:
    print('Sample looks Gaussian (fail to reject H0)')
else:
    print('Sample does not look Gaussian (reject H0)')
```

But there is no clear solution for checking n-dimensional data. You can test per feature or with projecting vectors to points based on your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I saw that blog bost and was following it but I saw it was two-dimensional. I'm trying with distance matrices also. Thanks!